# PHP update query with syntax error

Tags: mysql

Can anyone tell me why this doesnt work, and returns syntax error please?

```
$sql4 = "update apiStreetCheckGeneral 
         set (BBAverageSpeed, BBSuperFastBBAvailable, BBCommentary)
             values ('$averagespeed', '$superfast', '$bbcommentary') 
         where PostCode='".$values['PostCode']."'";
CustomQuery($sql4);
```

Comment: what does the syntax error tell you?

Comment: set them one by one instead, no other way is accepted in MySQL

Answer (score 1):

This is your query:

```
update apiStreetCheckGeneral set (BBAverageSpeed, BBSuperFastBBAvailable, BBCommentary)
     values ('$averagespeed', '$superfast', '$bbcommentary')
     where PostCode='".$values['PostCode'].
```

I am not aware of `update` syntax that uses a column list or `values`.  Set each one individually:

```
update apiStreetCheckGeneral
     set BBAverageSpeed = '$averagespeed',
         BBSuperFastBBAvailable = '$superfast',
         BBCommentary = '$bbcommentary'
     where PostCode='".$values['PostCode']."'"
```

You should learn, however, to use parameterized queries *especially* for `update` statements.

Answer (score 0):

Use query like below

```
$sql4 = "update apiStreetCheckGeneral 
         set BBAverageSpeed = '$averagespeed', 
          BBSuperFastBBAvailable = '$superfast', 
          BBCommentary = '$bbcommentary'
          where PostCode='".$values['PostCode']."' ";
CustomQuery($sql4);
```